# Isolate $A$ from $A\oplus(129^3A)$

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've been working through the following problem and I'm really stuck

Starting with the following three equations:

$$
a= (129A \oplus C)\mod 256 \\
b= (129B \oplus A) \mod 256\\
c= (129C \oplus B) \mod 256
$$
I xor'd both sides of the equation and translated this to this (modulus removed for simplicity):
$$
C = 129*A \oplus a \\
A = 129*B \oplus b \\
B = 129*C \oplus c
$$
Following this, I used substitution to find the following:
$$
A = 129*B \oplus b \\
\mathsf{\text{Substituting for }}B  \\
A=129(129C \oplus c) \oplus b\\
\mathsf{\text{Now substituting for }}C  \\
A=129(129(129A \oplus a) \oplus c) \oplus b\\
$$

Which then simplifies to:
$$
A=(129^3A \oplus 129^2 a \oplus 129 c \oplus b) \mod 256
$$

When I substitute for actual values, the above expression works.

Then

$$
(A\oplus 129^3A )\mod 256= (\oplus 129^2 a \oplus 129 c \oplus b) \mod 256 
$$

either equals 0 or 128.

Test values: $[A,B,C] = [223, 12,59]$ and $[a,b,c] = [100, 211, 183]$

**EDIT** A is an integer between 0 and 255, so I beieve that $A\oplus129^3A$ simplifies to $A\oplus129A$ becuse $\mod256$ would wipe out the unnecessary significant bits

### Question

**1. Is there any way to isolate $A$ from $A\oplus(129^3A)$?  Or, possibly $A\oplus129A$?**

**2. Have I made some fundamental error that I'm not catching?**